# How can you tell if javascript fails to open a window

Tags: c#, javascript

I am runnning a bit of javascript in the C# code-behind of an aspx program.

```
js = @"
    function OpenPaymentWindow()
    {
        childWindow = window.open('" + sessionDetails[1] + @"','Childwindow','status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,height=1000,width=1000');
    }
    OpenPaymentWindow();
    ";
```

This is pretty much the javascript in a nut shell.  Here is the problem.  Sometimes when this code is run -- and I know it is run because of the alerts I have placed before the window.open command -- the pop-up child window does not come up.  So, I assume that the "childwindow" variable must be null or something.  I want to make an addition to this code that checks for this and traps the condition where the window does not pop up and I am able to place an alert there.

Comment: I think you need to show us some more code.  All I see here is a string.

Comment: "childwindow" variable must be null or something"... bingo.

Comment: I think the only reason for the window not to come up would be if the user has a popup blocker. Usually they notify the user that they blocked something.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Best_practices

Comment: Would a javascript alert be blocked if the pop-up blocker is activated?

Answer (score 0):

Any JavaScript errors can be seen in the browser via the developer tools. For example in Chrome you can see the errors when you right click "inspect element" and click on "console". You can also see the exact location of the error in the resources tab if you select the location of your JavaScript code. I am a bit confused by you stating that you are running JavaScript in your code behind I am assuming that you are building the script in the code behind and then passing it to the browser when the page is loaded. In which case the error should be illustrated in the developer tools like I stated, otherwise your problem is that you are trying to make a window pop up on your server sort-to-speak =P.

Comment: While this is rather useful advice for people attempting to debug their own code, this doesn't really answer the question. When you get 50 reputation, you'll be able to comment anywhere, including on other people's questions.

Comment: Would an alert be blocked if the pop-up blocker be active?

Comment: Use breakpoints in the debugger, or console.log statements. Don't use alerts. That's not what alerts are for, and they change the way your program behaves.